# Cannot call Factory in Controller (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

I am staring to learn angularjs (please be kind).

I am trying to call `generatePollCode` method in the factory using the `createCtrl` but I got the message below:

`Error: [$injector:undef] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/undef?p0=pollFactory...`

Here's my code:

**App initialization:**

```
var app = angular.module("pollApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
```

**Factory:**

```
app.factory("pollFactory", function($http){

var factory = {};

factory.generatePollCode = function(){
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ){
        text = text + possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }

    return text;
  };

});
```

**Controller:**

```
 app.controller('createCtrl', function($http, $scope, $timeout, focus, pollFactory){
  $scope.submitPoll = function (){
      var x =pollFactory.generatePollCode();
      console.log(x);
  }
});
```

Thanks for anyone that can help me!

Comment: where is the factory located??in the same js file where ur controler located???if not have add that scrip to index

Comment: Yes, the factory and the controller files are in the same folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this. you forgot return factory object

```
app.factory("pollFactory", function($http){
 var factory = {};
 factory.generatePollCode = function(){
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ){
     text = text + possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
     possible.length));
   }
    return text;
 };
 return factory 
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to read the docs thoroughly and missed that part.

Comment: You are welcome. glad to help you. please accept the answer. thanks :)